# How to change CSS in media tag within @media only tags with jquery?

Tags: jquery, css

I am making a webpage for an iphone and ipad, say I have the following CSS:

```
#somediv {
background-color: white;
}

@media only screen and (max-device-width: 1024px) and (orientation:landscape) {
            #somediv {
                color:red;
            }       
        }

        @media only screen and (max-device-width: 1024px) and (orientation:portrait) { 
            #somediv {
                color:green;
            }          
    }
```

I have two question:
1) How to make it such that I can use a jquery selector that changes all of those properties for somediv to have "color: blue"?

2) How do I make it such that only the orientation:portrait one is "color:blue"?

Comment: You need to add more information about what you're actually trying to do. For example, the answer to (2.) the way you've worded it could be accomplished by directly editing the CSS and changing the word green to blue, so why do you need jQuery? What do you really want to do?

Comment: I'm not sure how familiar you are with jQuery. Do you just need [css()](http://api.jquery.com/css/)? e.g. `$("#somediv").css('color','blue');`

Comment: google `window.onorientationchange`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://github.com/paulirish/matchMedia.js/

is a good option for making media queries in javascript.